# Grails on AWS - How to update externalized config without deploying new WAR file?

Tags: grails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is it possible to update externalized Grails config file on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk (or EC2) without building and deploying a new WAR file?

I know that EC2 and Elastic Beanstalk allow for properties to be fed to the system to be used as configurations. I also know that config.groovy can be externalized into environment-specific files. The part I'm missing is how to change those externalized files on AWS without redeploying a new WAR file.

Thanks.

Comment: You could put put that file in an S3 bucket and run a script in crontab (using ebextensions) that periodically polls your S3 file for changes. Does that solve your problem? You could give your IAM Instance Profile read permissions to fetch this bucket.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html

Comment: Thanks Rohit, that seems like a solution. Let me take this approach and research it a bit more. I'll let you know how it goes. Meanwhile, if you have any example for the cron job, please feel free to share.